# How to retrieve data from the database to the second table after selecting the user in the first table?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three tables in my database as following:

**Employee Table: Username, Name, Job, DivisonCode**

**Course Table: CourseID, CourseName, GroupID**

**Employee_Course Table: Username, CourseID (The first key in each table is the primary key)**

I created two ListViews; one for retrieving the employee information from the Employee Table and the second one to show the taken courses (from Employee_Course Table) of the selected employee in the first ListView.

For the first table, everything works well and fine, but for the second table, I could not be able to retrieve the taken courses of the selected employee in the first table.

**So how can I do that?**

My ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Username" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="images/update4.png" Width="20px" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="images/cancel.png" Width="20px" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="UsernameLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="JobTitleTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("JobTitle") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="BadgeNoTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BadgeNo") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="EmpOrgTypeTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("EmpOrgType") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DivisionCode") %>' 
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="DivisionName" 
                            DataValueField="SapCode">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Divisions] WHERE [SapCode] = @SapCode" 
                            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Divisions] ([SapCode], [DivisionName]) VALUES (@SapCode, @DivisionName)" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Divisions]" 
                            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Divisions] SET [DivisionName] = @DivisionName WHERE [SapCode] = @SapCode">
                            <DeleteParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="SapCode" Type="Double" />
                            </DeleteParameters>
                            <InsertParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="SapCode" Type="Double" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="DivisionName" Type="String" />
                            </InsertParameters>
                            <UpdateParameters>
                                <asp:Parameter Name="DivisionName" Type="String" />
                                <asp:Parameter Name="SapCode" Type="Double" />
                            </UpdateParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [employee_courses] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [employee_courses] ([employeeId], [courseId]) VALUES (@employeeId, @courseId)" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [employee_courses] WHERE ([employeeId] = @Username)" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [employee_courses] SET [employeeId] = @employeeId, [courseId] = @courseId WHERE [ID] = @ID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="employeeId" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="courseId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="Username" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="Username" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <%--<asp:Parameter Name="employeeId" Type="String" />--%>
                <asp:Parameter Name="courseId" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Sorry for my first answer it was not relevant. What error do you get when you are trying to retrieve data from database? I assume you want to get courses names in the second listview

Comment: Yeah, this is what I want to get. I did not get any error. Everything works fine but when I select the employee in the first ListView, the course name will not be displayed in the second ListView

Comment: Then answer is to complex to give you solution. You should do everything in code behind not in aspx. First of all give datasource to the listview in code behind, then on event you can bind second data to second listview (also in codebehind) depends on which employee id you have selected.

Comment: Could you please give me some lines of code? Sorry but I am a new developer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get data from database. You can connect to your database through [System.Data.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) libraries. Then fill your listview with those data: [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx).
[ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) from msdn.
If you want to learn programming in asp.net you can check book from wrox [Beginning ASP.NET 4 in C#](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-ASP-NET-4-in-C-and-VB.productCd-0470502215.html)

For example
databinding looks like

```
//YourWebForm1.aspx.cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DataSet dataSet = GetYourDataFromDBMethode() // methode gets data from dataset like in msdn spec which I posted above in example;
ListView1.DataSource = dataSet;
ListView.DataBind();
}
```

Then on SelectedIndexChanged Event you bind data to the second ListView.

I can't write much more it would take much time.

Hope it helps.